# RSpec shared example for CRUD Controllers that might be nested or not

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've been trying to create a `shared example` to quickly and efficiently test controllers with CRUD operations that might also be nested.

I came up with this solution that works, but I feel that can be improved.

```
    module ApiHelper
  RSpec.shared_examples "a CRUD controller" do |model:|

    def self.controller_has_action?(action)
      described_class.action_methods.include?(action.to_s)
    end

    def self.model_belongs_to_associations(model)
      model.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name).nil?
    end

    resource_singular = model.name.underscore.to_sym
    parent_resource = model.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name).first

    #let(:parent_resource) { model.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name) }
    let(:records) { FactoryBot.create_list(resource_singular, 10) }
    let(:parent_record) { FactoryBot.create(parent_resource.to_sym) }

    before(:each) { request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] = "en" }

    describe "#show", if: controller_has_action?(:show) do
      context "when requested record exists" do
        let(:record) { records[rand 10] }
        before(:each) do
          get :show, params: {id: record.id}
        end

        it "succeeds" do
          expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
        end

        it "returns the requested record" do
          expect(json["id"]).to eq(record.id)
        end
      end
    end

    describe "#index", if: controller_has_action?(:index) do
      let(:params) {
        params = {}
        unless parent_resource.nil?
          params.merge!((parent_resource.to_s << "_id").to_sym => parent_record.id)
        end
      }
      before(:each) do
        get :index, params: params
      end

      it "succeeds" do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      end

      it "returns the factory names" do
        record_names = json.map { |c| c["name"] }
        expect(record_names).to all(be_a(String).and(include(resource_singular.capitalize.to_s)))
      end
    end

    # noinspection RubyDuplicatedKeysInHashInspection
    describe "#create", if: controller_has_action?(:create) do
      let(:request_params) {
        params = {}
        unless parent_resource.nil?
          params.merge!((parent_resource.to_s << "_id").to_sym => parent_record.id)
        end
        params.merge!(resource_singular => record_attrs)
      }

      before(:each) do
        post :create, params: request_params
      end

      context "when valid" do
        let(:record_attrs) { attributes_for(resource_singular) }

        it "succeeds" do
          expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
          expect(response.headers["Content-Type"]).to eql("application/json; charset=utf-8")
        end

        it "saves the new record" do
          expect { post :create, params: request_params }.to change(model, :count).by(1)
        end
      end

      context "when invalid" do
        let(:record_attrs) { attributes_for(resource_singular, :invalid) }

        it "fails" do
          expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        end
      end
    end

    describe "#update" do
      let(:record) { records[rand 10] }

      before(:each) do
        patch :update, params: {resource_singular => new_attrs, :id => record.id}
      end

      context "when valid" do
        let(:new_attrs) { attributes_for(resource_singular) }

        it "succeeds" do
          expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
        end

        it "saves update" do
          record.reload
          expect(record).to have_attributes(new_attrs)
        end
      end

      context "when invalid" do
        let(:new_attrs) { attributes_for(resource_singular, :invalid) }

        it "fails" do
          expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        end
      end
    end

    describe "#destory", if: controller_has_action?(:destroy) do
      context "when record exists" do
        let(:record) { records[rand 10] }

        before(:each) do
          delete :destroy, params: {id: record.id}
        end

        it "success" do
          expect(response).to have_http_status(:no_content)
        end

        it "remove record" do
          expect(model.all).not_to include(record)
        end
      end

      context "when requested record doesn't exist" do
        it "throws exception" do
          bypass_rescue
          expect { delete :destroy, params: {id: -1} }.to raise_exception(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
        end
      end
    end

    describe "#translations" do
      context "#show DE" do
        before(:each) { request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] = "de" }

        let(:record) { records[rand(10)] }

        it "returns the title in DE" do
          get :show, params: {id: record.id}
          puts(record.attributes)
          expect(json["name"]).to eq(record.name)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This can be called like this:

```
it_behaves_like "a CRUD controller", model: Island
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple notes.

1) You don't have to pass `:each` to `before` calls, it's [the default](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/8a287bd893889dba60e7bfce530727e7b009651e/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb#L14-L18):

```
# Before
before(:each) do
  get :index, params: params
end

# After
before { get :index, params: params }
```

2) The code may benefit from the use of [`be` matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers):

```
# Before
it "success" do
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:no_content)
end

it "succeeds" do
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
end

# After
it { is_expected.to be_no_content }
it { is_expected.to be_successful }
```

3) In some cases the content of `params` object is ambiguous, because `unless` returns `nil` when the condition is falsy. Here is an example of different `params` initialization:

```
# Before
let(:params) {
  params = {}
  unless parent_resource.nil?
    params.merge!((parent_resource.to_s << "_id").to_sym => parent_record.id)
  end
}

# After
let(:params) { parent_resource.nil? ? {} : { "#{parent_resource}_id".to_sym => parent_record.id } }
```

5) You're likely setting the language header in multiple places throughout the code, so a helper would come handy:

```
def set_language_header(lang)
  request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] = lang
end

before { set_language_header(:en) }
before { set_language_header(:de) }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, what do you think of this part `parent_resource = model.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name).first`? With multiple `belongs_to` associations obviously it will be problematic.